# How to make a simple auto-updating client (windows service)?

Tags: c#, auto-update

How to make a simple auto-updating client (windows service)?
Note: Am using .NET 2.0 client and .NET 4.0 IIS web server.

I thought that I would have a main startup .exe (Step 1 and 1.5) and a separate class (DLL) to be called after the update process for the rest of the work so the 'worker' DLL could be overwritten in the update procedure.

Is this the best way to make an auto-update client? 
All steps below are run at every timer interval and at at windows service / program startup.

1. Close then open web service connection
   1.5 Auto update client if web service version is newer in a transaction (download zipped binary file to update the client Program folder - usually just the "worker" dll file.)
2. Login to web method to get SecurityToken to be used for future web method calls
3. Upload local MessageLog (ideally before and after all processes)
4. Get client settings
5. Do main work processes (worker class)
6. Upload Local MessageLog
7. Logout web method
8. Close web service connection

Other Notes:

a. Client is only upgraded if that installation has a web server setting allowing them to receive updates, and their app version needs an update (compare version #'s).

b. Everything is over SSL.

c. I will secure the entire web service in addition to requiring a security token per web method (security token expires after 60 minutes or less).

d. The client config file is strongly encrypted (login creds to entire web service and for the specific installation)

e. I probably should download a MD5 sum of the app update binary file to ensure I have the correct file to install.  Does .NET implement MD5 in a standard way for Windows and on Mono framework for a Mac?

f. This custom program is not freely available on the web but only for some clients.

Comment: Why do you think that this needs to be a Windows Service?

Comment: @Cody.  My client program happens to be a Windows Service - that's the only reason.  I will also use it on a Windows Form for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a problem using ClickOnce? It is built into the .NET Framework and can be configured from Visual Studio.

Comment: I did not know it was built in to VS 2010.  Is it easy to use in my situation or is it more of a bother?

Comment: I did not know ClickOnce was built in to VS 2010.  Is it easy to use in my situation?  

Issues with ClickOnce in only 20 minutes of looking...
1 Rather configure my database then IIS.
2 IIS may block some of my files from being downloaded unless I configure IIS.
3 Want to avoid signing.  Every time you update manifest you must sign.
4 ClickOnce installations work only with IE.
5 Mapped Drive issues.


BUT For me the binary will be zipped and not using web browser.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228998.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228996.aspx

Comment: Also 50% of my clients are on Mac so will it update a Mac Package (using MonoObj) ?

Comment: How about System Center 2012 Configuration Manager?

Comment: ClickOnce is not for windows service as a service is not per user

Comment: Yes, but why are you mentioning this in this context? Could it be you misunderstood what he's saying? He doesn't want to update a service, he wanted to create a service to help him update his application. And that's what ClickOnce is for, instead of a service.